# move side navigation to right based on screen width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a side navigation for the desktop version of my site. Here is the CSS:

```
.sidenav {
  position: fixed;
  /*width set by col2 [16.66%]*/
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  /*top set by $*/
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

The CSS for the side navigation for mobile sites:

```
.sidenav {
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #2e2e2e;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  transition: 1s;
  padding-top: 15px;
}
```

As you can see from the CSS, I'm trying to get the sidenav on the right of the window for mobile. It stays on the left however. What am I missing? I have the duplicate settings because I'm trying to reset them from the desktop version. I think just adding `right:0` to the @media would make it the whole width of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this rule for the mobile sidenav styles:

```
.sidenav {
  left:auto;
}
```

The point is that browser has two rules at your version - `left: 0` and `right: 0`, so, he listen for the first rule and stands left.

Answer (score 1):

You need to unset the `left` property for `right` to apply:

```css
@media (/*...*/) {
  .sidenav {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    /*...*/
  }
}
```